# Do we have roomba_500_series stacks for ros groovy?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roomba_500_series package for groovy. Is this released or the existing one for fuerte and electric works for groovy as well ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57410/do-we-have-roomba_500_series-stacks-for-ros-groovy-?/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been tested with ros groovy on roomba 521 and it works fine by following similar steps as for ros electric and ros fuerte. Could anyone please close this question if satusfied with the answer as it's been tested.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0